# Custom Binder NOT working in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework

I am explicitly using a TypeBinder with the @As keyword in my controller action. And no matter what I do, the bind method is never called.

What determines the binder that is used?

I also turned my logging to ALL and I realized the Binder.bindInternal is never called either.

here is my binder

```
public class EmailTypeBinder implements TypeBinder<Email>  {

    @Override
    public Email bind(String name, Annotation[] annotations, String value, Class actualClass, Type genericType) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside email type binder");
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, Email.class);     
    }

}
```

Here is the controller action

```
    public static void send(@As(binder=EmailTypeBinder.class) Email email) {
       try {
        for(String key1:DataParser.parsers.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key1 + " value: " + DataParser.parsers.get(key1).getClass().getName());
        }

        for(String key : params.all().keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + " value: " + params.get(key));
        }

        System.out.println("ContentType: " + request.contentType);
        if(request.body == null) {
            System.out.println("request.body is null");
        }

        System.out.println("Available bytes: " + request.body.available());

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(request.body);
        String str;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("You entered String : " + str);
        }

        if(email == null) {
            System.out.println("email is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println(email.getMessage());
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the response from calling the controller

```
Key: application/xml value: play.data.parsing.TextParser
Key: multipart/form-data value: play.data.parsing.ApacheMultipartParser
Key: application/json value: play.data.parsing.TextParser
Key: application/x-www-form-urlencoded value: play.data.parsing.UrlEncodedParser
Key: body value: {email:{"from":"","subject":"Test Posted Subject","message":"This is my POSTED message","groups":[],"groupLists":["COS"]}}
ContentType: application/json
Available bytes: 0
email is null
```

In my routes I have

```
POST    /send                                   Application.send
```

The client is actually Groovy but this shouldn't matter because I've also tried with making it a Model, just a regular object in this project. Anyway you can think of

```
    public static void post(Email email) {

    def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:9000' )

    // perform a GET request, expecting JSON response data
    http.request( POST, ContentType.JSON ) { req ->
        uri.path = '/send'

        body = "{email:" + new Gson().toJson(email) + "}";


         // response handler for a success response code:
        response.success = { resp, json ->
            println "status: ${resp.statusLine}"

            // parse the JSON response object:
             println "  ${json}"
      }

      // handler for any failure status code:
      response.failure = { resp ->
        println "Unexpected error: ${resp.statusLine.statusCode} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}"
      }
    }
}
```

here is my Email class but I'm not sure its relevant

```
class Email implements Serializable {

// factory methods
public static Email createSimple(String subject, String message) {
    return new Email("", subject, message);
}
public static Email create(String from, String subject, String message) {
    return new Email(from, subject, message);       
}

public static Email createWithTemplate(String from, String subject, String message, String template) {
    Email email = new Email(from, subject, message);
    email.setTemplate(template);
    return email;
}   


public String getFrom() {
    return from;        
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public Set<String> getGroupLists() {
    return groupLists;
}

public Set<String> getGroups() {
    return groups;
}

public void addGroupList(String groupList) {
    groupLists.add(groupList);
}
public void addGroup(String group) {
    groups.add(group);
}

private void setTemplate(String template) {
    this.template = template;
}

// we must use the factory methods to create us
private Email(String from, String subject, String message){
    this.from = from;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

// only used for Gson JSON serialization/deserialization
public Email(){}

private String from;
private String subject;
private String message;
private String template;
private Set<String> groups = new HashSet<String>();
private Set<String> groupLists = new HashSet<String>();
```

}

The only way I can get this working is using the ApiPlugin from Chapter 4 example in the Play Framework Cookbook 
I can use this but the framework says it should be able to handle it simply by defining a TypeBinder but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are giving your email object as a json object but binders works on form params. Try to give your object as a form param or use gson in play to deserialize the object